# Как позиционировать элементы на flex по такому шаблону?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Подскажите, как на `flex` позиционировать элементы по такому шаблону без дополнительных оберток?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На флексах имхо единственный способ это `.flex.flex-wrap.gap-4>(.flex-grow-2.flex.flex-col.gap-4>div{$}*2)+.flex-grow-1{3}` (emmet-выражение под стили подобные tailwindcss)

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как бы вы описали этот вопрос текстом?

Comment: описание того, что именно вызвало у вас затруднение — вот это и было бы той информацией, по которой ваш вопрос можно было бы отыскать тому, кто столкнётся с тем же самым затруднением.

Comment: Обычно вопросы с похожими картинками задают с формулировкой вроде "How can I merge 2 flex-box rows in one using flex?" — не буду пытаться переводить, тем более, вы могли иначе представлять задачу. Вообще философский вопрос, зачем нам SO по-русски. Он работает как комьюнити, а не база знаний, в отличие от англ.

Comment: В том и дело, что задача такая - как бы я ее ни описал, искать все равно будут по другим запросам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз условия задачи требуют flex, а не grid, то воспроизвел картинку при помощи отрицательного отступа ¯\_ (ツ)_/¯

```css
.container {
  --rowHeigt:15vw;
  --colWidth:30vw;
  --gap:1vw; 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--gap)
}
.item:nth-child(1), 
.item:nth-child(2)  {
 width: calc(var(--colWidth) * 2);
 height: var(--rowHeigt);
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  width: var(--colWidth);
  margin-top: calc(0px - var(--rowHeigt) - var(--gap));
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Удивительно, что `flex` такого не может, даже через `flex-direction`.